# Loop Listbox SQL Insert with DateTime (incremented every 15 minutes)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, listbox

I'm trying to get all the items in my listbox, then perform a SQL insert, but on the datetime I want each listbox item to have a 15 minute delay.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
foreach (var item in myListBox)
{
    insert listitem1 with current date
    insert listitem2 with current date + 15 mins
    insert listitem3 with current date + 30 mins
}
```

The app i'm creating needs a time release function, meaning the user can not do anything until the date has passed.

I need to know how to loop the current date and 15 minutes for each item in the list.  I know how to do the SQL insert, but I don't know how to add 15 minutes to each row.

DB:
1 item1 09:00:000
2 item2 09:15:000
3 item3 09:30:000

Comment: What is the question here? Do you need help with sql or c#? I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
DateTime somedate = DateTime.Today;

for (int i = 0; i < myListBox.Count; i++)
{
    var increasedDate = somedate.AddMinutes(i*15);
    // and then insert myListBox.Items[i] with increasedDate 
}
```

Comment: perfect!  Worked a treat!  Cheers